# Focus the last element of a map html rendering

Tags: reactjs

In my react typescript project, I have a component which generates multiple `div` with the same `id` when I map through it.

```html
<div id="projectName" ref={ref} contentEditable="true" className="font-semibold focus:outline-none resize-none">{projectTitle}</div>
<div id="projectName" ref={ref} contentEditable="true" className="font-semibold focus:outline-none resize-none">{projectTitle}</div>
<div id="projectName" ref={ref} contentEditable="true" className="font-semibold focus:outline-none resize-none">{projectTitle}</div>
```

My goal is to set the focus on the last element of it when I click on my button. For that, I tried to use a method I found on another stack, but I can't have access to the `focus()` method like they use in the post.
I don't really know how I could process this.

```js
var size = document.querySelectorAll("[id=projectName]")
var last = size[size.length - 1]
last.focus() // error here
```

The error is the following one

> Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Comment: id should be uniq on your entire DOM Tree. Also div could not be focused without puting `tabindex=0`.

Comment: @Yanis-git I know id should be unique, but how could I find the last rendered element otherwise ? Moreover, if I just make a `getElementById` which return the first one of the list, I can use the `focus()` method on it.

Comment: or just get the containerID and target firstElementChild() you have multiple options here...

Comment: In these kinda 'dynamic scenarios' adding event listener to the container and utilising event delegation really helps...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `querySelector()`, please try to use refs when it comes to react. I see you are trying to do that but didn't implement fully.

```
export default function App() {
  let list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let elRefs = useRef([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let size = elRefs.current.length;
    elRefs.current[size - 1].focus();
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.map((x) => (
        <div
          id="projectName"
          tabIndex="1"
          ref={(el) => (elRefs.current = [...elRefs.current, el])}
          key={x}
          contentEditable="true"
          className="font-semibold focus:outline-none resize-none"
        >
          x
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Pass in a function to `ref` and keep appending to the `.current` array. And yes as mentioned you have to use `tabIndex` to make **non focusable items focusable**.

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-worker-xwi0p?file=/src/App.js:0-660)